# Toyota Prado TX-L dropping RPM and stalling randomly

Tags: toyota, stall, hunting-idle, prado

This is a 2009 Toyota Prado TX-L D4-D (160,000 km).

This issue started about a month ago, prior to which the car was running perfectly.

- Basically when the car is idle the RPM would drop randomly causing the ECO mode to come on for a few seconds and the car would rev aggressively as a result.
- In other situations, I’d be driving long distance and the car would drop its RPM, at times the 4LO and engine check light would come on & with a little acceleration the car would go back to life. However in other cases, the engine would turn off, resulting in me loosing steering assist as well as other indications on the dash.

Recently the car has had its fuel tank taken out twice! And a new fuel filter replaced. Anyone know what the issue might be?